# Vue : Conditional render of class

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, bootstrap-vue

I'am using vue-bootstrap , in the following code class come when step===1 but in else condition (!step===1) i want to render another class. First one is working fine , the else condition is not working. Steps is associated with Wizards. Can anybody help me out ?

```
 <div :class="{'d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center': step === 1, ' d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center': !step === 1  }"></div>
```

Comment: What is the data type of `step` here number or boolean? and also what is the actually values for step can be for both condition?

Comment: steps are related to wizard ( v-stepper ), they are numbers , there are 4 steps. I want to render different class step 1 and another set for step 2 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the if condition you are correctly using `step===1`, but for the else condition you need to use

```
step !== 1
```

which means that if `step` is not equal to 1 then add these classes. So, the template will be like:

```
<div :class="{
   'd-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center': step === 1, 
   'd-flex justify-content-center align-items-center': step !== 1
 }">
</div>
```

But as it seems that for `step===1` you are just adding `flex-column` and other classes `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` are common in both the conditions, so you can also try this:

```
<div 
  class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
  :class="{'flex-column': step === 1}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you need something like, if step is equal to 1 then align items in column else in row. You can bind class as shown below.

```html
<div 
   :class="step === 1 ? 
        'd-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center': 
        'd-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'">
  ...
  ...
</div>
```